# Custom Font in @react-pdf/renderer & Next.js

Tags: css, pdf, text, next.js, pdf-viewer

I am trying to define a custom font with react-pdf in a next.js project. However, I am not sure what I did wrong in this instance. The code work perfectly if I replace the src route with google API link. It would be nice if someone could point out the problem.

I can't import the text file like react as I'm using Next.js. However, CustomFont module in Next will create error.

```
// pdf.ts
import { Document, Page, Text, Image, Link, View, StyleSheet, PDFViewer, Font} from '@react-pdf/renderer';

Font.register({
  family: 'PrimaSerif',
  fonts: [
    {
      src: 'public/assets/font/PrimaSerif/FontPrimaSerif_Regular.ttf',
      fontStyle: 'normal', 
      fontWeight: 'normal',
    },
    {
      src: 'public/assets/font/PrimaSerif/FontPrimaSerif_Bold.ttf',
      fontStyle: 'normal', 
      fontWeight: 'bold',
    }
  ],
});
```

Comment: @KJ Okay I see... Thank you for the help. Let me try to load the font and see if that works.. This is kinda weird to me as I'm used to React. ._.